# Dock Run Does NOT Produce a Container

Tags: docker

I have been working literally all night (5 hours) trying to figure out why I can't get the "friendlyhello" container to run on my System.

- Windows 10 Pro
- Docker Toolbox
- Installed fine

I have tried a thousand different variants of this command, including the exact one from the docs:

```
docker run -p 80:3000 -d friendlyhello
```

and when I run it, the prompt is blank and when I run:

```
docker container ls
```

blank. I am absolutely out of ideas and I need help. I have searched for HOURS, and have come up with the same blank screen. Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Showing the Dockerfile would help a lot. It is difficult to tell what the problem is

Comment: What is the output of `docker container ls -a`? (without `-a` the default behavior is to list only the running containers). If your container exits, it won't be listed, but it has been created, started, exited and you might see it if you list all of them.

Comment: Assume this is the one that's mentioned https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/

Comment: What is the output of `docker logs <container-name>`? It looks like your container is quitting, rather than remaining running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remember to start the "Docker Desktop" such that there is a little whale running in your bottom left systems bar. If you have forgotten to start this, then no docker command will get your docker image running, though the commands are available in powershell.

Comment: I originally had different issues, and got them resolved. I reinstalled Docker Toolbox several times and in the end, I did in fact, forget to restart the system. Once I restarted the system, I was able to use the commands with no issue. 

I never even thought about it. Half of me is happy you gave me the solution, half of me wants to waterboard myself for not even thinking about it lol

Thanks a million.

Comment: Ha ha, I know the feeling! I have been through the same process, as docker (in Powershell) does not throw as clear error message that this is indeed the issue. I am glad you got it figured out :)